# Give document fields different priority in ElasticSearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I have data:

```
{"NAME": "BRIDGE CAMBODJA", "NAME": "CAMBRIDGE APARTMENTS", "NAME":"KULAMAN BRIDGE"}
```

I have the following query:

```
'{"query": {"query_string": {"query": "BRIDGE"}'
```

and I want what will appear is:

```
{"NAME": "BRIDGE CAMBODJA", "NAME": "KULAMAN BRIDGE", "NAME": "CAMBRIDGE APARTMENTS"}
```

How do I modify my search to set the field ranking / priority?

Comment: Your data is invalid.  Your "what I want" is also invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your required result, by using the [boost parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) directly in the query and querying for `NAME` which begins with `BRIDGE`, ends with `BRIDGE`, or which contains `BRIDGE`.

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "NAME": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "NAME",
            "query": "BRIDGE*",
            "boost": 10
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "NAME",
            "query": "*BRIDGE",
            "boost": 5
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "NAME",
            "query": "*BRIDGE*",
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66095448",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 11.0,
        "_source": {
          "NAME": "BRIDGE CAMBODJA"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66095448",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 6.0,
        "_source": {
          "NAME": "KULAMAN BRIDGE"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66095448",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "NAME": "CAMBRIDGE APARTMENTS"
        }
      }
    ]
```